# Cursor is not displayed in custom edit text when it get focus after typing one letter it will display.

Tags: android, android-edittext

In Custom edittext Cursor is not displayed when it get focus.My edit text is customized with some styles.when i enter some data above edittext and press enter custom edittext will be focus but cursor is not displayed if i enter any one letter it will display if i remove letters and focus other edittext and focus again custom edit text cursor is not displayed.

I try all suggestions.Like

```
android:cursorVisible="true"



?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#a8a8a8"/><!-- This is the exact color of android edit text Hint -->
    <size android:width="1dp" />
</shape>
```

event try to set `EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
editText.setText("");`

it work but it effect when user again click on edittext it show empty.

I try all stackoverfolw sugestion which will match but not work for me.

My custom edittext is implemented from TextWatcher and edittext.